# How to specify a monospace font in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, fonts

I want to specify a monospace font in a `Text` widget:

```
Text("I would like this to be monospace.")
```

How can I do that? I don't care about the actual font so long as it is monospace because this is for a developer-only screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [official docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts), you should:

1. Import the font files.
2. Declare the font in the pubspec.
3. Set a font as the default.
4. Use a font in a specific widget.

Now I will put these steps from the document here, and you can read the entire document if you want more details:

##### Step 1:

After you have your fonts ready (`ttf` for example), you add them to your project directory under the assets folder, for example (from the link above):

```
awesome_app/
  fonts/
    Raleway-Regular.ttf
    Raleway-Italic.ttf
    RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
    RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
```

##### Step 2:

Declare the font in `pubspec.yaml`, example:

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

##### Step 3:

You have two options for how to apply fonts to text: as the default font or only within specific widgets.

In your case, you want to use the font in a specific widget, so you do:

```
child: Text(
  'Roboto Mono sample',
  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
),
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a lot of hoops to jump through! I was hoping to be able to just specify "monospace" like in CSS. I guess it does make sense however to have to explicitly specify exactly what you want in an app so that you don't get unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) package. I was looking for monospace, like you and decided to use this. Super quick and easy.

Comment: don't forget to also follow the guide under [Bundling fonts when releasing](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts#bundling-fonts-when-releasing). because if not, `google_fonts` will still use dynamic font loading (download the font on runtime) even in the release version.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextStyle ts = TextStyle(fontFamily: "monospace",
  fontFamilyFallback: <String>["Courier"]);

Text tx = Text("I would like this to be monospace.", style: ts);
```