Flutter Web: tabularFigures() not working on mobile
Update: If i'm using a default Flutter Font it works as expected, so the error only occurs with imported fonts.
As you can see in the two pictures below, tabularFigures() is working in Chrome on PC as expected but in the Browser of mobile devices (e.g. Safari) it doesn't work. I'm using the custom font "Outfit". Is there a way to fix this bug or is there a workaround?
   SizedBox(
      width: 60,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: Text(
          score(),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: ThemeColorStyles.selectedTheme.kPrimaryFontColor,
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            fontFeatures: const [
              FontFeature.tabularFigures(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
   );

Expected: (In Chrome on PC)

Instead: (Safari on iPhone)


After some research i think it is necessary to import a monospace font for custom fonts.
Check this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75284947/how-to-specify-a-monospace-font-in-flutter
